# Stop google indexing resource routes with Laravel

Tags: laravel, robots.txt

I have just launched a link curation website that uses a controller to redirect the users to a link.

I have a route set up:

```
Route::get('/redirect/{id}', 'LinksTableController@show');
```

This takes the ID of a link row from the database and redirects the user to that url.

The issue is that I can see google is indexing all of these routes. If I do site:domain.com it shows me all of my links in the database with url's such as:

```
/redirect/10
/redirect/20
```

And so on.

I have a robot.txt file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /redirect/*
Disallow: /admin*
```

But want to make sure I have it set up correctly before I flood google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
Disallow: /redirect*
```

The following Google link covers it very well: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_txt?csw=1